# Itext android studio problems

Tags: android, itext

I have a problem regarding the quality when printing an itext generated PDF file. Here's what I do:

1. create the pdf on an android tablet with iText
2. Transfer the PDF to a PC where it looks perfectly fine
3. Print the PDF with an epson printer (tm u-220)
4. The print has several issues:

   - there is a margin at the top (about 20f)
   - the letters can't be read

Comment: Sorry it is unclear what you mean with your question. Please provide more information. You need to generate a PDF on your android device? And you want to print it afterwards? Whats ticket style? Where did you read what? ...

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, now the pdf is created, the issue is that when you print the file created from my phone to my computer to an Epson printer TM U-220b goes wrong, the impression the lessens, can you help?

Comment: Sorry but it is difficult to understand your english: 1. You generate a PDF file on your phone. 2. You print that file on your printer 3. You are not happy with the quality or what does " the impression the lessens" mean?

Comment: Excuse me, A/1 Yes i create the pdf in my tablet with Itext and all are perfect after i move pdf into my computer, A/2 Im trying to print in my epson tm u-220, A/3 Cause i look pdf perfect but when im print in my printer make margin top like 20f, and letters can't read....

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I assume that you are not satisified with the quality of the printed PDF document. There are several possible reasons for that.

1. The 'Low Resolution Printing' is enabled (itext calls it [AllowDegradedPrinting](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfWriter.html))
2. The images in your PDF have a bad quality to start with
3. You use a font which you didn't embedd / or some other font related problem (e.g. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958538/problems-with-chinese-fonts-in-itext-pdf-on-windows-machines))